# redis is working in local but not working in server

Tags: node.js, redis

I have a redis server which is working fine in my local but in ubuntu server is not working can someone gives the comment for installing redis in server

it is not working even with docker it is working only while i am running in local[image]

```
const redis=require('redis');

var redisClient:any;

(async () => {
  try {
    redisClient = redis.createClient({ socket: { port: 6379 } });
    await redisClient.connect();
    // const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    //   port:"6379",
    //   host:'redis-service'
    // });
    
    redisClient.on('connect',()=>{
      console.log('server connected to redis')
    })
    
    redisClient.on('ready',()=>{
      console.log('Client Connect to redis and ready to use')
    })
    
    redisClient.on('error',(err:any)=>{
      console.log(err)
    })
    
    redisClient.on('end',()=>{
      console.log('Server disconnected from redis')
    })
    
    process.on('SIGINT',()=>{
      redisClient.quit()
    })
    console.log('connected');

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
  }
})()
export{
  redisClient
};
```

Comment: Please add all steps executed when installing redis in ubuntu server.

Comment: i have attached my code

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that Redis is not already running on the server. You can check this by running the command ps aux | grep redis. If Redis is running, you should see a line with the redis-server process.
2. Confirm that Redis is properly installed on your server by running redis-cli ping. If Redis is installed and running, it should return "PONG"
3. Check the Redis configuration file (redis.conf) and ensure that the IP and port settings match the settings on your local machine.
4. Make sure that the Redis server has the necessary permissions to access its data directory and that the correct ownership and permissions are set on its files.
5. Verify that the firewall rules on the server allow incoming connections on the Redis port (usually 6379)
6. Check for any compatibility issues between the version of Redis that you're running on your local machine and the version of Redis that's running on the Ubuntu server. If there's a version mismatch, it may be necessary to upgrade or downgrade one of the installations.
7. Try to run the Redis server with verbose output by running the command redis-server -v, this can give you some more information about the errors that are causing the server to fail.
8. Look at Redis log files, usually located in /var/log/redis for further clues about the cause of the problem.